Combinatorics Games Question
Let 'n' be a positive integer. A and B play a game with 'n' cards.
First, A writes one integer on each of 'n' cards. After that, B repeats the following operations.
Choose two cards and let the integers written on them be 'a' and 'b'.
Erase both numbers written on the chosen card and write a – b on one card and b – a on the other card.
The goal of B is to make the numbers written on all cards 0 after a finite number of operations.
(1) Show that when n = 3 , A can write integers so that B cannot achieve its goal.
(2) Show that when n = 4 , B can always achieve its goal regardless of how A is written.

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult How to ask a good question for further guidance.
